# What does this statement do in java

Tags: java, arrays, new-operator

```
int[] a=new int[]{};
```

*what does this statement do in java? I come across this statement. Let me understand the purpose of {} in the statement*

Answer (score 1):

It creates a new empty `int` array that it refers to with the variable `a`. The `{}` is an empty initializer:

```
int[]                    // The variable type is int[]
    a                    // Its name is "a"
        =                // Initialize it with...
            new int[]    // Create a new array whose size comes from the initializer
                {};      // An empty initializer
```

Another way to write it would be:

```
int[] a = new int[0];
```

---

Here's an example of using an initializer with contents:

```
int[] a = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
System.out.println(a[2]); // 3
```

That's actually a bit archaic, nowadays you're allowed to leave the `new int[]` part out:

```
int[] a = { 1, 2, 3 };
System.out.println(a[2]); // 3
```

Comment: @BoristheSpider: Yeah, as I was breaking it out I noted the absense of the `0`. :-)

Comment: what is the difference between int[] a = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 } and int[] a = { 1, 2, 3 }

Comment: @LOGES: Nothing, your second example is just more modern syntax. I forget when it was added to Java (maybe Java 5?). Before it was added, you needed the more verbose version.